# Can't access array by index, but can iterate with foreach

Tags: php

How come that I can't access array by index `$obj->property[0]` but can iterate through the array (each has only one value) and then get the value.

```
foreach($obj->property as $inner_obj)
{
    foreach($inner_obj->property as $inner_inner_obj)
        echo $inner_inner_obj->property;
}
```

If I access array by index I get `Undefined offset: 0`

**Edit: Output of var_dump**

```
array(1) {
 [0]=> object(FooClass)#141 {
   // yadda yadda
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add to your question the output of: `var_dump($obj->property)`?

Comment: print_r($obj->property) maybe it is not array is object

Comment: Looks like an object to me, not an array ?

Comment: I guess it's an object implementing [`Iterator`](http://php.net/iterator) but not [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess)

Comment: You can iterate through object properties tho. Check this link; http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: The fact that you can, doesn't make it a good practice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make class by `implements` `Countable, Iterator` you can make a object that work with `foreach` but it is not array

Comment: So, there is no other way (except the foreach, of course) to access the value I need? Im using Yii framework btw. Also CModel class implements IteratorAggregate, ArrayAccess

Answer (score 0):

`$obj` is not array its `stdClass Object` and

because of that `$obj->property[0]` will show you `Undefined offset: 0`

try to use it like this for getting 1st value of `property`

```
$obj->property->property;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looping over properties of an array in a foreach. With [0] you explicitly try to access it as an array. You can have your object extend ArrayObject and make php access your object as an array which is what you want I think.

The interfaces that gives the ability to use your object as an array:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php

The object itself which you can extend:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

Imo, it's never a good idea to loop over an object without array interface as it means you are using public variables. My suggestion is to always make them protected or private unless not possible otherwise (SOAP?). You can access them by getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

The `$obj->property` could be an array without having key `0`.
The keys in your array might not be numeric. So your array might be an associative array not a regular.
If you want numeric indexing try this:

```
  $numArray = array_values($obj->property);
  var_dump($numArray);
```

If you want to access the first value of an array use:

```
  $first = reset($obj->property);
```

It works if your variable is an `array`.